# Deco simulator not working even with Xcode and the simulator installed?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the newest IOS simulator but when I click on the simulator tab at the top of the Deco IDE it says no simulators are available and that I need to install Xcode. However I have Xcode and the simulator installed. Any tips?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal run `xcrun simctl list` and if this returns

> xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

then you need to assign Xcode version to Command Line tools.

Open Xcode->Preferences->Locations and under the Command Line tools select Xcode version. After that reload Deco and it should work.

Comment: Tried it. Deco took some time to show the simulators. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open Xcode and install the Xcode Tools when prompted. [Or follow this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/).